# view .htm file on sdcard and search words in it

Tags: html

When I click a .htm file in file manager, it opens the html viewer which has no search feature. How to open the file with the bundled browser? I could type the path (file:///mnt/sdcard/...), but it's too long.

Answer (score 0):

You can try opening it in an HTML editor like [WebMaster's HTML Editor Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.welant.webmaster.DEMO). It has syntax highlighting, and a search function. It also as a Pro version with additional features.

If you don't like that, there are several other HTML editors in Google Play.

Comment: I don't want to install extra packages. "HTML editor" sounds huge. Maybe there's a way to copy the full file path to clipboard and paste it in the browser?